# How do access cart Items and use find to check if a product exist in an array using the handle add product function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, find, undefined

```
     import React, { Component } from 'react'
        import '../Pages.css'
        import { Box, Card, CardContent, Typography, CardMedia, Button} from "@mui/material";
        import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
        import styled from "styled-components";
        import WaveSurfer from 'wavesurfer.js';
        import ye from '../ye.mp3';
        import yepic from '../Musicbox/yepic.jpg'
        
        
        const data = [
          {
            songImg: ye,
            songName: "Burna Boy - Ye",
            songGenre: "Afrobeat",
            songDetails: "125 BPM,  3:45mins",
            songPrice: "N4300",
          },
        ]
        
        
        const WaveformContainer = styled.div`
        display: block;  
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 100px;  width: 100%;
        background: transparent;
        `;
        
        const Wave = styled.div`
        width: 50%;
        height: 90px;
        `;
        
        const PlayButton = styled.button`
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          width: 60px;
          height: 60px;
          background: #EFEFEF;
          border-radius: 50%;
          border: none;
          outline: none;
          cursor: pointer;
          padding-bottom: 3px;
          &:hover {
            background: #DDD;
          }
        `;
        
        class Boxthree extends Component {
        
          
        
          state = {
            playing: false,
          };
        
          componentDidMount() {
            const trackthree = document.querySelector('#trackthree');
        
            this.wavethree = WaveSurfer.create({
              barWidth: 1,
              cursorWidth: 1,
              container: '#wavethree',
              backend: 'WebAudio',
              height: 40,
              progressColor: 'blue',
              responsive: true,
              waveColor: '#EFEFEF',
              cursorColor: 'transparent',
              fillParent: false,
              minPxPerSec: 15, 
            });
        
            this.wavethree.load(trackthree);
          };
        
        
          handlePlay = () => {
            this.setState({ playing: !this.state.playing });
            this.wavethree.playPause();
          };
        
          constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              cartItems: []
            };
          }
        
          
        
          handleAddProduct = (value) => {
        
            const valueExist = this.cartItems.find((item) => item.id === value.id);
        
            if(valueExist){
              this.setCartItems(this.cartItems.map((item) => item.id === value.id ? 
              {...valueExist, quantity: valueExist.quantity + 1}: item)
              );
            }
              else{
                this.setCartItems([...this.cartItems, {...value, quantity: 1}]);
              }
           
          }
        
          setCartItems = (cartItems) => {
            this.setState({
              cartItems
            })
          }
        
        
         
        
            render() {
        
              // const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
            
              return (
                <div className='NewContainer'>
        
                    {data.map((value,index) => {
        
                      return(
                        <Grid container >
            
                        <Grid item md={4} >
                          <div className='cardbox'>
                          <Card sx={{display: 'block', }}> 
                             
                            <Box sx={{padding: '10px', position: 'relative', }} key={index}>
                            <CardMedia square 
                            component='img'
                            height='200'
                            src= {yepic}   
                            alt='splash'/>
                
                      <WaveformContainer className='wavecon'> 
                      <PlayButton className='playbtn' onClick={this.handlePlay}> 
                
                      {!this.state.playing ? 'Play' : 'Pause'}
                
                      </PlayButton>
                      <Wave id="wavethree"/> 
                      <audio id="trackthree" src={ye}/>
                
                      </WaveformContainer>
                            </Box>
                          
                            <CardContent>
                            <Typography>
                                  {value.songName}
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography>
                                {value.songGenre}
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography>
                                {value.songDetails}
                                </Typography> 
                                <Box  sx={{ display: 'flex',justifyContent: 'space-between', }}>
                                <Typography>
                                  Exclusive
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography>
                                  Lease
                                </Typography></Box>
        
                                <Button variant='contained'
                              sx={{ bgcolor: '#3E0660', color: 'white', display: 'flex', borderRadius: '30px', }} 
                              onClick={ this.handleAddProduct(value)}
                            >
                              <Typography sx={{ paddingLeft: '5px',  paddingRight: '5px',  paddingTop: '3px', paddingBottom: '3px' , }}>Add To Cart</Typography>
                
                              <Box sx={{ bgcolor: 'white', color: 'black', borderRadius: '30px', paddingLeft: '5px',  paddingRight: '5px',  paddingTop: '4px', paddingBottom: '3px'  }}>
                                <Typography>{value.songPrice}</Typography></Box>
                            </Button>
                            </CardContent>
                          </Card>
                          </div>
                        </Grid>
        
                       
                        </Grid>
        
                      )
                
              })}
        
                </div>
              );
            }
                        
          
        
         
        };
        
        export default Boxthree;
```

I get an error when I try to access cart Items and use .find in the handle add product function

I tried accessing cart Items and using .find to check if a product I clicked on exist, but it keeps displaying Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find') at the value exist constant in the handle Add Product function.

Comment: Please post your code as a [mre].

Comment: I just added the sample code

Comment: Your class has not property named `cartItems`, but you class does have a property named `state` that has a property named `cartItems` - so try `this.state.cartItems` instead. You are also overwriting your state and losing `playing` prop

Comment: I tried it, Its still showing the same error